# Animate rotation using step Function with a certain degree in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rotation

I have a div. It rotated at -35 degree( set in CSS file) , I want to click it to rotate it back to 0 degree

here is my code JS file

```
$("div#words").on("click",function(e){
$(this).animate({
        "height":"200",
        "border-radius":"200"
        },{duration:500,step:function(now,fx){
            $(this).css("-ms-transform","rotate("+now+"deg)");
            $(this).css("-webkit-transform","rotate("+now+"deg)");
            $(this).css("transform","rotate("+now+"deg)");

            }},function(e){
                });
});
```

Now it rotate about 180 degree,  how can i set it to a certain degree ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This question is always answered**
[Jquery rotate a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517966/jquery-rotate-a-div)

**JS:**

```
$("div#words").on("click",function(e){
$(this).animate({
        "height":"200",
        "border-radius":"200"
        },{duration:500,step:function(now,fx){
            $(this).addClass('box_rotate');
            }},function(e){
                });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.box_rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* Chrome, Safari 3.1+ */
    -moz-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* Firefox 3.5-15 */
      -ms-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* IE 9 */
        -o-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* Opera 10.50-12.00 */
         transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.50+ */
}
```

Add a class and define the class. This is an easy and simple way to do that.

Comment: Thanks. It worked but the animation and rotation did not move at the same time. the rotation finished first then animation start. Is there any other way to move them together ?

Comment: @user3265085 fiddle.jshell.net/vwatf/1 this, how do you think about it?

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/vwatf/23/    like this  , but i can rotate and make it round at the same time ?

Comment: uh... i think i know why ... just time difference i have to make animation faster to catch up the transform..

Comment: As i can see your question is answered :)