# Jquery 1.8.2 and rotation on Smart TV

Tags: jquery, css, samsung-smart-tv

I'm trying to rotate an image with `jQuery` on version `1.8.2`. I can't change this version.

Here is what I've tried:

```
$("#test").css("-webkit-transform","rotate(-90deg)")
$("#test").css("-moz-transform","rotate(-90deg)")
$("#test").css("-ms-transform","rotate(-90deg)")
$("#test").css("-o-transform","rotate(-90deg)")
$("#test").css("transform","rotate(-90deg)")
$("#test").tabs('rotate', -90)
$("#test").rotate(-90)
$("#test").rotateAnimation(-90)
```

None of these lines work

My navigator is a custom one by `Samsung` on a Smart TV. Here is the result of `navigator.userAgent` command:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (SmartHub; SMART-TV; U; Linux/SmartTV+2014; Maple2012) AppleWebKit/537.42+ (KHTML, like Gecko) SmartTV Safari/537.42+
```

**Edit** : 
This seems impossible for now. Does it exist an other way to make a rotation without using `HTML5`?

**Edit2** :
Here is some working code:

```
$("#myVideo-container").get(0).style.webkitTransform = 'scale(-0.5,-0.5)';
$("#myVideo-container").get(0).style.webkitTransform = 'translateY(-600px)';
```

I've tried to move from `video` to `div` rotation but still not rotating.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rotate a div using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020904/how-to-rotate-a-div-using-jquery)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517966/jquery-rotate-a-div and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776015/jquery-animate-a-rotating-div

Comment: First are you sure that is jquery working well on your smart TV ?

Comment: I'm using `jQuery` all long but I can't find how to rotate. I thought the problem came from this old version (September 20th, 2012) but I'm not even sure about that.

Comment: @TylerH, my problem is different because it's from a Smart TV. I've tried every single code line you've shared with me. None of these work as I explained on the description.

Comment: @bobbystouket try to test if css transforms are supported by your Smart TV browser - you can run this test http://css3test.com/

Comment: Thanks for the tip @easwee, I've tried it. It seems that the rotation is possible but when I do it on my Smart TV, nothing happen (or strange things). I've added some positive tests.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work for me in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mbho2bjj/

Of course, JSFiddle only has between jQuery 1.7.2 and 1.8.3 to test with.

I did however add semicolons to the end of your statements.

```
$("#test").css("-webkit-transform","rotate(-90deg)");
$("#test").css("-moz-transform","rotate(-90deg)");
$("#test").css("-ms-transform","rotate(-90deg)");
$("#test").css("-o-transform","rotate(-90deg)");
$("#test").css("transform","rotate(-90deg)");
$("#test").tabs('rotate', -90);
$("#test").rotate(-90);
$("#test").rotateAnimation(-90);
```

Comment: It's also working for me with `Chrome`, `Safari`, `Mozilla` but not on this Smart TV..

Comment: You should probably tag this question with smart tv or something so experts there can help.

Comment: You can import any version of any library (jQuery included) by clicking "External Resources" in JSFiddle and pasting in a link to a CDN.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't necessarily need to use jquery. Using JS you can do it very easily.

Try this

```
document.getElementById("test2").style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
```

Comment: Could you please share the sample widget?

Comment: I've shared everything I can I think. This is just a rotation that works on Chrome but not on this Smart TV. I've done a `css3test.com` test. The result is strange because it seems possible to rotate but when I do it, it's not working.